# celery sqlalchemy open a different session(and not close it) on every query?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery

All. I have set up celery with my Flask App, and I have a question how celery manage sqlalchemy session. Say I init my celery app my doing this(using this [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/)):

```
celery = make_celery(app)

#set up a test task
@celery.task(name='testcelery', ignore_result=True)
def test_celery():
    db_session.execute("""INSERT INTO [dbo].[testconstraint]
                      VALUES (1)
                   """)
    db_session.commit()
```

Now in my main view.py from Flask App, add a route

```
@app.route('/testcelery', methods=['GET'])
def testcelery():
    tasks.test_celery.apply_async()
    return 'just test'
```

Everything works fine except that every time I hit /testcelery, it initiates a session(I'm using MS SQL SERVER) and does not close/remove it(unless I KeyInterupt celery from command line). It addes up a lot of sessions in Activity Monitor.

[image]

Each of them shows like this:

[image]

I've tested add `db_session.close()` or `db_session.remove()` at the end of that celery task, but still not working.  Anyone has any idea what might be the cause?

EDIT: Here's my engine and session creation in `database.py`

```
engine = create_engine('connection string')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating and holding onto the SQLAlchemy Engine object? The engine handles pooling of connections - if you're creating an engine every time you create the session, you may have a grouping of engines each holding onto a "pool" of one session.

Comment: I have engine and session created in a file `database.py`. I've added the code snippet into op. And db connections are maded from other code by doing `from .database import db_session`. Is this the right way to do?